# Berry-Esseen Theorems. Please help

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-explanation, central-limit-theorem

> Suppose $X_i\sim U[0,1]$. Is it true that, for some finite constant $c$, $$\left|\mathbb P\left(\sqrt{12n}\left(\bar{X} - \frac12\right)\le x\right) - \Phi(x)\right|\le\frac cn$$ uniformly in x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but not because of the Berry-Esseen theorem.  That result gives a uniform bound of order $O(1/\sqrt n)$.  Your inequality follows from the Edgeworth expansion (see, eg, *Limit distributions for sums of independent random variables* by Gnedenko and Kolmogorov, section 45, or *An introduction to probability theory and its applications*, vol 2, by Feller, chapter 16).  The idea is that the correct cdf is approximated by the gaussian cdf plus a certain function of $x$ divided by $\sqrt n$, plus an error uniformly bounded by $O(1/n)$.  In your special case, the $1/\sqrt n$ term vanishes.